# SQL 'select' Query with 3 conditions

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM REVIEW 
WHERE REVIEWERID =5 AND APPRAISEECONFIRMYN='Y' AND HRCONFIRMYN = NULL
```

Are 2 'AND' conditions allowed like this? I'm not getting the correct output. There are 2 records in the database that fulfil the above conditions. When I remove the last condition `'HRCONFIRMYN = NULL'` and execute, I get the correct output.

How can this be solved? I need to check all 3 conditions whilst searchng the records.

Comment: perhaps HRCONFIRMYN isn't indeed null?  Does "HRCONFIRMYN IS NULL" work? Depending on the DBMS and the settings "= NULL" may not work (and is not ANSI compliant)

Comment: ok, Jonathan. Ya Jim, 'HRCONFIRMYN IS NULL' worked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To compare the [**`NULL`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29) values, you have to use the `IS NULL` predicate instead of `= NULL` like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM REVIEW 
WHERE REVIEWERID = 5 
  AND APPRAISEECONFIRMYN = 'Y' 
  AND HRCONFIRMYN IS NULL
```

Comment: this saved a lot of time for me by luck!

Answer (score 2):

- use `OR` instead
- group your condition
- use `IS NULL` when comparing with NULLs

query,

```
SELECT * 
FROM REVIEW 
WHERE (REVIEWERID =5 AND APPRAISEECONFIRMYN='Y') OR
      HRCONFIRMYN IS NULL
```

Comment: THANK YOU KUYA, 'OR' SHOULD BE REPLACED WITH 'AND' RIGHT?

Comment: @sanuj: Please don't SHOUT.  Yes, for your purposes, OR should be replaced by AND and the parentheses are then unnecessary.

Comment: sorry, i didnt shout. may be u mistook so because of my capital letters right, oh god, i would like to tell you that it doesn't mean anythng like what u thought of.. i was using capslock letter to type in sql managmnt studio, so meanwhile when i typed comment here, i forgot to off the capslock.